# Using SCM Bootstrapping on Maven Projects in Multiple SVN Repositories

Tags: maven, version-control

I have a project split into a large number of modules, which are split among a couple of dozen SVN repositories. (Hey, office politics, what can I say?)

Anyways, I would like to use the Maven SCM plugin to check out the parent project, then run the bootstrap routine to check out the rest of the modules (then possibly run the Eclipse plugin to create the Eclipse configuration). I would also like the option to update existing sources if they already exist.

The documentation gives me hints that this is possible by defining multiple executions, but actual implementation details seem lacking.

Has anyone gotten this working, and can they share that knowledge?

Jason

Comment: Are these modules just have dependencies on each other or do these modules are a multi-module build?

Comment: In a sane environment, this would be a multimodule build. I do not work in a sane environment. 

So, some of these checkouts might be JARs (database access), while others may be a Webservice (WAR). WARs may have dependencies on the JARS.

At this point I don't even care about building. I just want to bootstrap the checkout and possibly the eclipse project config.